# R a factor sampling methode

Tags: r, sampling

I would like to produce a direct sampling with the following object :

```
v <- c("piment","aubergine","carotte","oignon","chou","pommeDeTerre","Na")
n <- 12

## TEST 1 : crach R
tmp <- data.frame(matrix(rep(v,n), ncol = n))
expand.grid(tmp)
```

But this will produce a matrix of too large size (2.176782336e+9 possibilities). So I have to study a sampling, but I don't know how to make it representative of my population.

Comment: Use can use `sample()`  to draw random sample and perform permutations.

Comment: How to be sure that the sample looks like it was given? How many samples do I need to be a representative ?

Comment: Representative of what? What's your population?

Comment: @camille , if `expand.grid(tmp)` are all the possible assemblies (prints). I would like to select/sample enough of them to cover the result space efficiently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your study sample consists of `v`, resampling `length(v)` values (which is 7) from `v` gives you a valid bootstrap sample. Repeat this resampling `B` times and you have (non-parametrically) bootstrapped your study sample in an appropriate way.

Make sure to always fix the random number generator, so that your resampling procedure can be reproduced at any instance.

```
set.seed(1) # fix random number generator
B <- 1e4L

boot_fun <- function(data, B, n_sample) {
  boot <- replicate(
    B,
    data[sample(seq_along(data), n_sample, replace = TRUE)],
    simplify = FALSE
  )
  return(boot)
}
out <- boot_fun(data = v, B = B, n_sample = 12L)

#> out[[1]]
#[1] "chou"         "pommeDeTerre" "chou"         "chou"         "chou"         "pommeDeTerre" "carotte"      "chou"        
#[9] "piment"       "carotte"      "piment"       "oignon"
```

Comment: That sounds great to me! But I have to vary the size of my observations (`n` in my short cas). In your answer the length is equal to the length of the list `v`, while in my example I had to sample 12 times in the vector of 7

Comment: I have edited the answer to also include the option to specify `n_sample` instead of a fixed number (which was 7 previously).

Comment: Cool ! It work for me.